# Output Values of a Collection object

Tags: anylogic

I have a collection variable and I would like to store its data in a file (csv,excel,...) but i don't know how. I tried to use the window during runtime but only a limited amount of data is visible there.

[image: Described above]

Answer (score 1):

Write the results into a csv or Excel file. You can use the following snippet as an inspiration.

I have an Excel file linked to the object excelFileOutput. And my collection has 2 dimensions; if yours is 1D, you won't need the second `get`.

```
//---Writing the values-----------------

for (int i=0; i<myCollection.size();i++)
{
    
    int x = ((Integer) myCollection.get(i).get(0)).intValue();
    excelFileOutput.setCellValue(x, 1, i+2, 1); //value,sheetName or number, row, column
    
    Double z = ((Double) myCollection.get(i).get(1));
    excelFileOutput.setCellValue(z, 1, i+2, 2);
    
    String y = ((String) myCollection.get(i).get(2));
    excelFileOutput.setCellValue(y, 1, i+2, 3);
    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a replicated text object:

Replicate it as many times as the `myCollection.size()`, set its dynamic text to `myCollection.get(index)` and set the dynamic y-value to `100+(index*10)` to show them all below each other